# ScrollView stops components from expanding

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to have my cards expandable and fill the while area of the screen while they are doing the change form height 50 to the whole screen (and don't display the other components)

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DisciplineView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack {
                    Card(cardTitle: "Notes")
                    Card(cardTitle: "Planner")
                    Card(cardTitle: "Homeworks / Exams")
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
    }
}

struct DisciplineV_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DisciplineView()
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct Card: View {
    @State var cardTitle = ""
    @State private var isTapped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: isTapped ? .infinity : 50)
            .background(
                VStack {
                    cardInfo
                    if(isTapped) { Spacer() }
                }
                    .padding(isTapped ? 10 : 0)
            )
    }
    
    var cardInfo: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(cardTitle)
                .font(.title).bold()
                .foregroundColor(isTapped ? .white : .black)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: isTapped ? "arrowtriangle.up.square.fill" : "arrowtriangle.down.square.fill")
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        isTapped.toggle()
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}

struct Card_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Card()
    }
}
```

[image]

here is almost the same as I would like to have, but I would like the first one to be on the whole screen and stop the ScrollView while appearing.
Thank you!

Described above:
I would like to have my cards expandable and fill the while area of the screen while they are doing the change form height 50 to the whole screen (and don't display the other components)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty much what you are trying to achieve.

Basically, you have to scroll to the position of the recently presented view and disable the scroll. The scroll have to be disabled enough time to avoid continuing to the next item but at the same time, it have to be enabled soon enough to give the user the feeling that it is scrolling one item at once.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var canScroll = true
    @State private var itemInScreen = -1
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text("\(item)")
                                .onAppear {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        proxy.scrollTo(item)
                                        canScroll = false
                                        
                                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                            canScroll = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
            .disabled(!canScroll)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image]